# C++ what does #define followed by one identifier and later used like a namespace mean?

Tags: c++, macros

I am new to C++ and tasked with understanding the open source H265 codec found [here](https://github.com/strukturag/libde265). In the code (specifically [here](https://github.com/strukturag/libde265/blob/master/libde265/de265.h)) we have a `#define` followed by only one identifier, and this identifier is later used like a namespace. The particular example that has be stuck is the following:

```cpp
// This is how it is defined
#define LIBDE265_API

// In some other file elsewhere in the project
LIBDE265_API de265_error en265_encode(en265_encoder_context* e) {
    std::cout << "Entered encode function" << std::endl; // I added this for debugging
    // function does something here
}
```

The above is the only place in the entire project that a definition is given for the function `en265_encode()`. However, when calling this function from a different file I got an assertion error and started printing checkpoints to try and trace exactly how the variables are setup to arrive at that error. So I have something like this:

```cpp
// Different file
std::cout << "About to encode..." << std::endl;
en265_encode(ectx);
std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
```

When I run it it prints `About to encode...` and then it dies by the assertion error. It never prints `Entered encode function`. How is this possible if the definition I gave above is the only definition of `en265_encode()`? My hunch is that I do not understand how `#define` is being used in this context. If it is something else entirely I would greatly appreciate some insight.

And even if it is something else I am still confused about how `#define` is being used here. Thanks.

Comment: That `#define` means replace `LIBDE265_API` with nothing. So using that macro has no effect on the function definition and whatever problem you are having it's not caused by that macro.

Comment: What kind of assertion error? That's pretty vague. Could you attach some logs? And first of all - when calling that function from the other file (which doesn't have definition for `LIBDE265_API` I assume), does this code even compile?

Comment: So if that means replace LIBDE265_API with nothing, why even use it before a function declaration?

Comment: The assertion error is checking that a particular flag on the `en265_encoder_context` object is `false` and is failing because that flag is actually `true` so I'm trying to track down why it never got set to `false`. I'm really trying to get an exact stack trace, and currently trying to make `backtrace()` work so I can get some more detailed logs but it seems like apart from that my print statement in `en265_encode()` should have run

Comment: @thehumaneraser Probably because under some circumstances that definition is overridden with compiler options. This kind of technique is often used on Windows to handle DLLs.

Comment: And yes it does compile

Comment: @PookyFan I just checked and the declaration for `en265_encode()` is in a header file which is included in the file that calls it so that makes sense why it has no issues compiling. But that still does not explain why my print statement is not triggered?

Comment: @thehumaneraser If you look at this [file](https://github.com/strukturag/libde265/blob/master/libde265/de265.h) it's clear that macro isn't always defined as nothing.

Comment: As @john has said, the macro may be defined elsewhere in different compilation units. From its placement, it looks like it's used to specify a calling convention - and, if that is mismatched between definition and invocation, you'll likely get a crash.

Comment: @john Apologies for my ignorance, I am very new to c++. I think I am beginning to understand it though. I see now that the macro could be `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__attribute__((__visibility__("default")))` which would make a lot more sense

Comment: I think that clears up that it is not an issue with the macro. I'm still very confused about how my print statement could possibly not run but that is not an issue with the macro as I originally thought it might be

Comment: @thehumaneraser If simply calling a function causes a crash the two likeliest explanations are stack overflow, or a corrupt stack. Plus what Adrian said above, your calling code and the function itself have been compiled in different ways and have different understandings of how a function should be called. Given the context that seems the likeliest explanation.

Comment: @john It is not just calling a function. There is an assertion error ([here](https://github.com/strukturag/libde265/blob/master/libde265/encoder/encoder-syntax.cc#L1484), line 1484) that fails. I'm just trying to trace how all the variables got setup to trigger that but it is perplexing to me that my print statement in `en265_encode()` gets skipped...

Comment: @thehumaneraser OK understood. Then I would say that the most likely explanation is that something is wrong with your build process which means that the modified code isn't being called. There is no way that a line of code can just be skipped like that.

Comment: @john Alright, thanks for your input. I agree that it can't possibly just be skipped so I'll look into how it's built and see if I can find some issues there.

Comment: @thehumaneraser You could test this theory by (for instance) changing the name of the function. If your code still compiles and links then that would prove that the function is being picked up from somewhere else.

Comment: @john Just tried this and sure enough with a different name it still compiles and I get the same behavior. So it must not actually be calling that function but that is the only place in the project it is defined... the plot thickens...